# Minimum input voltage for this Transistor circuit

Tags: transistors

I have a circuit below, which I am using in a Coil Gun to amplify a pulse which is generated when a projectile passes close to a coil. I was able to get it to work, however I had the question of what is the maximum voltage that I can pass as an input to this circuit(at the microphone pin)?

My guess is that it would be just maximum ratings of the transistor from the datasheet, but is there anything else that might effect that value?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty clear that the circuit is designed for a supply voltage of around 9V (the quiescent voltage at the output is about 4V), which means that the quiescent current through the first stage is about 375 µA.

Also, the common-base configuration of the first stage is intended to work with low-impedance sources (such as when a speaker is used as a microphone), so the input signal level is best described in terms of current, rather than voltage.

It should be obvious that if the input signal exceeds ±375 µA, the input stage will begin to distort the waveform, since the first stage will be forced into cutoff. The actual voltage swing that this represents depends on the actual impedance of the signal source. For example, if the source impedance really is 8Ω, then the maximum voltage swing would be about ±3 mV.

Comment: I have a coil with a resistance of around 50 ohms and generates a voltage of 0.45V , so its 0.008A, luckily, I did not see any distortion.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it will be the maximum reverse bias voltage of the base-emitter region, usually around 5 volts is the limit.